# Using metamask to sign ERC20 approvals

Tags: web3js, metamask, infura, smart-contract-wallets

I have a frontend UI and NodeJS backend with web3js to interact with my smart contract. I'm able to interact with the smart contract using metamask by using `window.addEventListener("load",onDocumentLoad)` function in `index.js`. However I have a couple of user driver operations from the frontend UI, which has to interact with certain functions in the smart contract.

I'm using express in `server.js` and jQuery functions to pass values from frontend to backend, however the problem is when i need to interact with the smart contract I don't have access to the `web3` which was created in `index.js` because these are two different JS files. I tried `module.exports` to export the value of the `web3` object in `index.js`

Question: How can I use metamask instead of infura to sign and send transactions? I dont want to store user's private key to sign transactions.

Comment: Web3js is for the front end, not the back end, you need to understand that

Comment: Yes i got that and we should be able to use metamask to sign transactions right? how can that be using web3js

Comment: Web3.js is a set of libraries that use HTTP or IPC connections to interact with local or remote Ethereum nodes.
If we use JavaScript to develop a DApp, we often need to use web3.js (or optionally ethers. js).